Cannot instantiate a read-only class which extends another read-only class in PHP?
This is my class hierarchy:
readonly class ParentClass {
    public function __construct(
        public string $lastName
    ){
    }
}

readonly class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function __construct(
        public string $firstName,
        public string $lastName
    ){
        parent::__construct($lastName);
    }
}

$child = new ChildClass('John', 'Doe');

I got an exception with message that "Cannot modify readonly property ParentClass::$lastName".
I've read many articles or answers of questions in Stackoverflow but nobody talked about this case or I didn't find out.
Why did I got that error?

Does it work if you use explicit assignment instead of the parameter list shortcuts?

@Barmar Still get same error with using explicit assignment.

You are trying to redefine the property in the child class. You can't do that.
Define the property only in the parent class.
readonly class ParentClass {
    public function __construct(
        public string $lastName
    ){
    }
}

readonly class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function __construct(
        public string $firstName,
        string $lastName // No promoted property here. 
    ){
        parent::__construct($lastName);
    }
}

